# Marklogic search query

Tags: marklogic

I am new to marklogic. Can anyone please provide me  a script to get document name and XML file contents of the document, and also uploaded/created timestamp by passing attribute value.

Answer (score 3):

This question is hard to understand.  Documents in MarkLogic are identified by URI, not name.  If you know the URI, then just do

```
doc($uri)
```

to get the contents.  The last-modified time for a document is stored as document property, which you can get using the XPath properties axis like

```
doc($uri)/property::*:last-modified/string()
```

There are other ways to get the document properties, like the [`xdmp:document-properties()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-properties) api call.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by @eric-bloch, if you did a search, you can determine the uri using `fn:base-uri()` or  `xdmp:node-uri()`. For example like this:

```
for $d in cts:search(doc(), cts:and-query(()))[1 to 10]
return fn:base-uri($d)
```

Note: the empty and-query is a little trick to get all documents returned. The 1 to 10 predicate makes sure you don't get the entire database returned at once, but only the first ten. If you would add an order by on the last-modified property, you could get the ten oldest or newest documents this way.

Comment: I think you meant "but only the first ten" (not two).